# How to get parent entity information from child entity without looking up relationship in a DB

Tags: .net-core

I have a .Net program with nested entities or aggregates.
The aggregate root is received when a request is made to the application. The application does not have access to DB.
During the execution of the program, notifications have to be sent.
The problem is that the parts of the program where the notification is created only have access to one of the child entities, but have to include information that is present in the aggregate root, or some parent entity.
Normally, it would be possible to just get the additional info by looking up its relationship to the other objects using the Id of the entity. But in this case, the application does not have access to the DB.

One approach would be to add the extra information to each entity - which I don't like because entities now have properties that may or may not be relevant to that entity.

Another approach would be to have an in-memory cache where the entities and their relationship are stored - the problem here is that the application is highly concurrent and a central data store might cause a bottleneck. Also, this introduces another moving part which could introduce a bug e.g. retrieving an entity whose id is not in the cache.

Another approach would be to link entities together such that every entity has access to the root entity - but entities may have different root entities, which means I'll have to do type-checking to find the correct entity root.

Any suggestions?
Is there a standard way in which this problem is normally addressed?

Comment: How many possible parent entities are there?

Comment: Currently only 2 - but this could become more as the functionality expands.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a web application...are the child entities something like deserialized JSON objects that are detached from a `DbContext`? Or were they created via `new ChildEntity()`?

Comment: The web application receives a message, which then gets deserialized into a class. On the web application side it is completely detached from the DbContext. The application that sent the data to the web application created the entity from the DB and had access to the DbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another approach would be to have an in-memory cache where the entities and their relationship are stored - the problem here is that the application is highly concurrent and a central data store might cause a bottleneck

Using some sort of singleton cache should not bottleneck your application. ASP.NET Core Dictionary reads are lightning fast. There is a new dictionary type introduced in ASP.NET Core 8 called `FrozenDictionary<TKey,TValue>` that was designed for even faster reads, and supports concurrent reads. The cache can be populated by one initial connection to the database at application startup.

Make the `FrozenDictionary<TKey,TValue>` cache a singleton service that you can then inject into the controller that needs it (assuming you're using MVC).

*This singleton service is effectively an in-memory representation of the ParentEntity database table. Be mindful of the size of the table so you don't run into memory issues. For example, if the ParentEntity table is full of images stored as `byte[]` or `BLOB`s.*

**Program.cs** (register the parent entity cache singleton service)

```
using System.Collections.Frozen; // available only in ASP.NET 8 and later

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// register a singleton service of type FrozenDictionary<long, ParentEntity>
// the key is the id, the value is the parent entity.
// this will serve as the ParentEntity cache
builder.Services.AddSingleton(services =>
{
    // make a temporary connection to the
    // database to fetch all the parent records
    using MyDbContext db = new();
    // fetch all the parent entities into a dictionary
    // the key is the id, the value is the parent entity
    return db.ParentEntities.ToDictionary(x => x.Id).ToFrozenDictionary();
});

var app = builder.Build();

// remaining Program.cs code...
```

**HomeController.cs** (inject the parent entity cache into the controller)

```
using System.Collections.Frozen; // available only in ASP.NET 8 and later

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly FrozenDictionary<long, ParentEntity> _parentEntityCache;
    public HomeController(FrozenDictionary<long, ParentEntity> parentEntityCache)
    {
        _parentEntityCache = parentEntityCache;
    }

    // accessible via "/Home/GetParentEntity?id=12345"
    public IActionResult GetParentEntity(string? id)
    {
        if(long.TryParse(id, out var idLong)){
            if(_parentEntityCache.TryGetValue(idLong, out var parentEntity)){
                // do stuff with the parent entity here...
            }
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```